# quoting problem with JPA2 (EclipseLink) and PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, quotes

With PostgreSQL, I have to double-quote all identifiers or they'll be implicitly lower-cased. I'd prefer to preserve case since "lastLoginAttemptIpAddress" is so much more readable than "lastloginattemptipaddress".

I have created an orm.xml file with  (full contents below). That caused EclipseLink to quote most of the identifiers, but it specifically did not quote the column name when defining a foreign key constraint. How can I tell EL to quote *all* identifiers?

I have also tried using quotes in the explicitly specified table / column names to cause EL to quote identifiers. First and foremost, that doesn't work either -- same behavior. In addition to that, (1) that forces me to specify names twice (I already did so in the property accessor names) and in a manner that is invisible to refactoring tools, (2) it is wrong -- the quotes aren't part of the name, (3) it forces me to fix quoting at POJO level when it is actually a specific trait of the database system I am using.

orm.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<entity-mappings version="1.0"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/orm orm_1_0.xsd">

    <description>description here</description>
    <persistence-unit-metadata>
        <persistence-unit-defaults>
            <delimited-identifiers />
        </persistence-unit-defaults>
    </persistence-unit-metadata>

</entity-mappings>
```

entity class:

```
@Entity
public class UserX {

    ...

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "UserX_id_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "UserX_id_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    public int getId() { ... }

    ...

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false)
    public UserX getModificationUser() { ... }

}
```

the generated query (note the missing quotes around the column name):

```
ALTER TABLE "UserX" ADD CONSTRAINT "FK_UserX_modificationUser_id" FOREIGN KEY (modificationUser_id) REFERENCES "UserX" (id)
```

Comment: You managed to create two accounts - I've merged them for you. I also converted your comment below from an answer, to an actual comment. If you're having problems logging in to Stack Overflow, please visit http://meta.stackoverflow.com and let us know.

Comment: I did not confirm any of the account creation dialogs, not even those SO tried to disguise as "Login using your Google account".

Answer (score 3):

Seems to be a bug that the foreign key column are not quoted.  Please log the bug in EclipseLink and vote for it.

Does the DDL fail?  A work around would be to define the DDL in a script, or switch just that column to be all lower case.

Comment: I have logged this as a bug and use hand-made DDL scripts. Thank you for your answer. 

Sadly I cannot vote you up without creating yet another website account (StackOverflow even claims I can authenticate using my Google account instead of OpenID, then suddenly tries to sign me up with OpenID anyway without me ever intending to do so. Gotta love this...)

Comment: James, even when I log in using that forced-on-me account, I still cannot vote you up. I'm sorry.